# Unexpected backslash when converting from hex to binary number

Tags: command-line, bc, numeric-data

I am trying to convert a hex line to binary in `bash`, but the output includes a backslash.  Can someone explain why?

Input:

`for i in 3D3D516343746D4D6D6C315669563362; do BIN=$(echo "ibase=16; obase=2; $i" | bc); echo $BIN; done`

Output:

`11110100111101010100010110001101000011011101000110110101001101011011\ 0101101100001100010101011001101001010101100011001101100010`

Comment: The `for` loop is needless since there's only one item.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX implementation of `bc` splits output lines to a maximum of 70 characters, using the backslash as a *line continuation character*.

If you have the GNU version of `bc`, you can override this behavior using the `BC_LINE_LENGTH` environment variable e.g.

```
$ printf 'ibase=16; obase=2; %s\n' 3D3D516343746D4D6D6C315669563362 | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc
111101001111010101000101100011010000110111010001101101010011010110110101101100001100010101011001101001010101100011001101100010
```

From `info bc`:

```
'BC_LINE_LENGTH'
     This should be an integer specifying the number of characters in an
     output line for numbers.  This includes the backslash and newline
     characters for long numbers.  As an extension, the value of zero
     disables the multi-line feature.  Any other value of this variable
     that is less than 3 sets the line length to 70.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the output using some "bashisms": `echo ${BIN//[$'\r\n\\']}`

example:

`for i in 3D3D516343746D4D6D6C315669563362; do BIN=$(echo "ibase=16; obase=2; $i" | bc); echo ${BIN//[$'\r\n\\']};done`

You can also use the env variable `BC_LINE_LENGTH`, that GNU bc will use to adjust the line length (0 is unlimited).

example:

`for i in 3D3D516343746D4D6D6C315669563362; do BIN=$(echo "ibase=16; obase=2; $i" | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc ); echo $BIN;done`

Answer (score 0):

If *GNU* `bc` is not available, this also works:

```
echo "ibase=16; obase=2; 3D3D516343746D4D6D6C315669563362" | \
    bc | tr -d '\\\n' ; echo
111101001111010101000101100011010000110111010001101101010011010110110101101100001100010101011001101001010101100011001101100010
```

(Too-long output intentionally not wrapped.)